# how can i check if my activity is partially visible not completely?

Tags: android

I have two activities A and B.A is app type activity and B is dialog type.when A is in foreground and B is called A goes to foreground and it's onPause is called but not onStop. so is there a way if i get to know in my onPause if my activity is partially visible not completely visible ?

Answer (score 2):

When your activity is visible and if any other dialog opens then your activity will be Pause  and `onPause()` method of the activity will be called. If your activity is completely invisible then `onStop()` method of the activity will be called.